# Error inflating class button

Tags: android, class, button, inflate

I just started learning Computer Science and Android development.  I've been going through some helloworld demos to try and learn.

So going wild, I tried to rewrite a program that has one button for two buttons using the onClickListener.  While I don't have any compiling errors, my program is force closing on me:

> 01-05 11:20:33.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multbuttontest/com.example.multbuttontest.MultiButtonActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class button

My XML file looks like so (Sorry I suck at formatting):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MultiButtonActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and code:

```
package com.example.multbuttontest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MultiButtonActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button button1, button2;
int touchCount1, touchCount2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_button);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setText( "Touch Button 1!");
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setText( "Touch Button 2!");
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            touchCount1++;
            button1.setText("Touched b1 " + touchCount1 + " times(s)");
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            touchCount2++;
            button2.setText("Touched b2 " + touchCount2 + " times(s)");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

This is strictly just for my learning purposes, and the code does suck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that your layout file? It's missing a closing RelativeLayout tag. And shouldn' those be <Button/> tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that might help you out.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private TextView txt1;
    private Button btnCount,btnClear; 
    private int num1 = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    btnCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


}

public void sendMessage(View view) 
{
     txt1.setText("You have clicked"+ (num1) + "times");
     num1++;

}

public void clear(View view)
{
    num1 = 1;
    txt1.setText("You have clicked"+ (num1) + "times");
}




}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_clear" 
    android:onClick="clear" />

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@+string/pushed" />
```

Output: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Again thanks so much!  I'm gonna try this out.  If I could hug you I would.

Answer (score 8):

It's not `button`, it's `Button`. The XML tag points to the java class in the framework. And Java is case sensitive.

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Hooooly cow I'm an idiot.  But thank you so much!  Still need to work on it, but I'm so much happier now!